# JavaScript: turn a string into a number and then turn it back to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers, parsefloat

I'm receiving some data which I need to turn them to numbers, make some computation with that and then I need to use the same data in another place but as a string.
I'm using `parseFloat()` but the problem is that it already removes the letters part of that number.

```
    const string = parseFloat("100 MB")
    console.log(string) // 100
```

Is there something else other than `parseFloat()` to turn a string into a number but somehow keep the `MB` part of the string if I want to turn it back as the original string?

Comment: Just keep the initial value around? There isn't a "number, which also includes text but is still a number, even though there is a string somehow attached to it".

Comment: If you already have the string then you already have it.  const orig = "100 MB", const numberPart = parseFloat(orig)

Comment: Just to be more precise. The data is a table and each table cell has some values ("100 MB", "2 GB", "6 TB"...) so i need to convert them to numbers in order to apply filters to the table. But then i need to use the same values in the filter items but they need to be strings just as the initial value. However the below answer is a good workaround.

Comment: `const originalCellContent = cell.getContentInAppropriateWay()`. Use the original value later. You don't have to reconstruct it (which risks the reconstructed value not matching the original representation).

Comment: It goes to filter before it gets rendered in the table cell. Anyway, i thought maybe theres some workaround other than `parseFloat()` to make me achieve what i need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const string = "100 MB";

let toArr = string.split(' ');
// do your math computation
let num = parseFloat(toArr[0]) * 10.25 + 1.14; // whatever
let result = ''.concat(num, ' ', toArr[1]);
console.log(result);
```